# How to remove a cecil instruction

Tags: .net, mono, mono.cecil

I have this method:

```
public int Test()
{
    ExternalClass cls = new ExternalClass();
    return cls.ExternalMethod();
}
```

I need to change it using IL Injection so I can pass the type as parameter and remove the direct object creation, like this:

```
public int Test(ExternalClass cls)
{

    return cls.ExternalMethod();
}
```

I am able to add the additional parametr using <>.Parameters.Add(***_*___**) and generate the new Assembly.

The issue is that I am not able to remove the instruction for the new object creation. Below are the lines I used to remove that.

```
ILProcessor ilProcessor = <<MethodDefinition>>.Body.GetILProcessor();
ilProcessor.Remove(<<newobj instruction>>);
```

Once I tried to call the modified assembly method like below, it's throwing the error "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."

```
ExternalClass ext = new ExternalClass();
int i = prg1.Test(ext);
```

I know I may need to handle memory allocation related stuff, too. I would appreciate if anybody is able to provide additional steps to be implemented here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't just remove the `newobj` instruction; you're left with an invalid program, as the runtime told you.  Here's roughly how the original method translates to IL:

```
public Int32 Test()
{
    .local ExternalClass 0;

    // ExternalClass cls = new ExternalClass();
    newobj class ExternalClass();
    stloc.0;

    // return cls.ExternalMethod();
    ldloc.0;
    callvirt Int32 class ExternalClass:ExternalMethod();
    ret;
}
```

If you remove only the `newobj` instruction then the `stloc` instruction will have nothing on the stack to store in the local.  You need to turn the method into this:

```
public Int32 Test(ExternalClass cls)
{
    // return cls.ExternalMethod();
    ldarg.1;
    callvirt Int32 class ExternalClass:ExternalMethod();
    ret;
}
```

So you need to do three things:

1. Add the argument to the method signature,
2. Remove everything up to *and including* the `ldloc` instruction.
3. Insert a `ldarg.1` instruction at the beginning of the method.

Optionally, you may also remove the `ExternalClass` local.  (This will be optimized away by the JIT-compiler, but will bloat the IL image.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to keep using the local and just replace `newobj` with `ldarg`?

Comment: @svick That would be another possible approach, yes.

Comment: Thanks you all. I hope if more args to be passed, the additional chanages mentioned will increase accordingly.